# AWS ECS Docker: Not pointing to Drupal path and giving error You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, drupal-8, amazon-ecs

Drupal 8 directory structure is like below

**drupal -> Web -> Index.php**

I have below files

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal:latest
    container_name: drupal
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    restart: always
```

`DockerFile`

```
FROM drupal:8.6-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    git \
    mysql-client \
    vim \
    wget

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

RUN wget -O drush.phar https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/download/0.4.2/drush.phar && \
    chmod +x drush.phar && \
    mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush

COPY apache-drupal.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www/web
```

`apache-drupal.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/web/"
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory "/var/www/web/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/web/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/web/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I am accessing via Public IP of Drupal Cluster it will only show `error.log` & `access.log` file only. Not Drupal whole project.

Something missing in path?

Comment: you must access using IP:8081

Comment: Hi @LinPy Now I am getting `You don't have permission to access this resource.` without port number

Comment: You have to proxy pass to the port `8081`

Comment: With XX.XX.XX.XX:8081 it is still giving same error `Forbidden : You don't have permission to access this resource`

Comment: does it work locally? also what is command for your Dockerfile, does it every start apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you catch some kind of collision.

- Your `drupal:8.6-apache` image contains Drupal in `/var/www/html` folder, but you map your volume to `/var/www/` folder inside container. This breaks it at all.
- Your `apache-drupal.conf` file points to `/var/www/web`, but project is already inside `html` (we are in container)

The simple way to make it works is to perform 3 modifications (if it's enough for you to get mapped logs only)

1. Change volume mapping in `docker-compose.yml` to `/var/www/web`
2. Change `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` in `apache-drupal.conf` to `/var/www/html/`